# Does java println effect math equations?

Tags: java, math, println

Why does `System.out.println(404 / 10 * 10 + 1)` equal 401 rather than 405?

Comment: `404 / 10` is a integer division, meaning result is 40 ... multiply by 10, add 1, you got 401

Comment: The second dupe is a dupe of the first dupe :-D